Knowing which query was used to create field in QGIS
I have received a GeoPackage containing a layer with different fields created by several queries, but I don't know what the person actually did in those (and of course, I can't ask the creator himself).
Is there a way to know what query has been used to create a field in QGIS? I don't really have the time to try and recreate the table from scratch and guess what has been done.
I tried looking in the layer's properties, the QGIS manual, and, of course, forums, but I couldn't find an answer yet.

My guess would be that it is not possible to reverse engineer queries just by looking at the attribute table. In a geopackage the styling of the layer can be preserved, so if data in your layer was created using the attributes form (e.g., default values for attributes), there might be a change that these were preserved as well (Properties > Attributes form > check fields of interest).

This is why proper attribute naming and saving intermediate steps/attributes is important. If the attributes are named properly, trust the provider. If not, ask them.
